# Switch-case not works for AVR Atmega32 Microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmelstudio, winavr

Hello Friends i dont know what happen neither switch-case nor if,else statement works for me i want to give some data to both PORTB & PORTD when some specific data are come to the PORTA register in my "switch block" previously i used PINA instead of PORTA but it still not works but when i start debugging and giving some data by giving PORTA=0b00001110 it easily gives values PORTB=0b00000010....
please help..

```
/*
 * robotic_arm.c
 *
 * Created: 2/3/2015 10:39:25 AM
 *  Author: Shrikant Vaishnav
 */ 

#define F_CPU 1600000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{ DDRA=0x00;//make PORTA as input
  DDRB=0xFF;//make PORTB as output
  DDRD=0XFF;//make PORTD as output

    while(1)
    {

        switch(PORTA)
        {

        //First Three conditions for Robotic ARMs

        case 0b00001110:
         {
            PORTB=0b00000010;
             _delay_ms(50);
             break;
         }

         case 0b00001101:
         {
            PORTB=0b00001000 ;
             _delay_ms(50);
            break; 
         }

         case 0b00001011:
         {
            PORTB=0b00100000 ;
             _delay_ms(50);
             break; 
         }

         //Condition for Direction Change of Motors of Robotic Arms
         case 0b00000110:
         {
             PORTB=0b00000001;
              _delay_ms(50);
             break;

         }

         case 0b00000101:
         {
             PORTB=0b00000100;
              _delay_ms(50);
             break;

         }

          case 0b00000011:
          {
              PORTB=0b00100000;
              _delay_ms(50);
              break;

          }

        //Now Driving Robotic Car
         case 0b00000010:
         {
             PORTD=0b00000010;
              _delay_ms(50);
             break;

         }

          case 0b00000001:
          {
              PORTD=0b00000001;
               _delay_ms(50);
              break;

          }

        default:
        { 
            PORTB=0b00000000; //0ff motors when no signal sent
            PORTD=0b00000000; //OFF DRIVING CAR
             _delay_ms(50);
            break;

         }


    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps your external switches are incorrect, or give a brief transient value. In the latter case, the `default` statement might be invoked. As a suggestion, why don't you try just writing PORTA input to PORTB output continually and look at what happens. And BTW in the statement `case 0b00001101: { PORTA=0b00001000; ...}` did you really mean to write to `PORTA`?

Comment: You probably did not intend to define a clock frequency of 1.6GHz? The _delay_ms() requires a properly set F_CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the higher pins of PORTA are all `0`? If not, then none of the cases will match.

You can try

```
switch(PINA & 0x0F)
```

instead. This will ensure that the higher pins will not cause the cases to fail.

Comment: But sir  if I ground the upper four bit (nibble ) to 0  then according to you this logic works?

Comment: Yes, the code looks good, except for the second case, where you write to PORTA instead of PORTB.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the the register to test is not `PORTA` but `PINA`. 
You have to distinguish between 'port x' when referring the hardware unit and `PORTx` when talking about accessing the special function registers.
Reading 'port A' means reading the `PINA` register.

- `PORTx` are the registers where you set the output (or if configured as input) the pull ups
- `PINx` are the registers that hold the current input level at the pins. (if configured to output they got of course the same value as the `PORTx` (but with some delay)

On modern AVRs you also can write to the `PIN` registers if you want to toggle the output. This saves a few cycles compared to the normal way of reading the `PORT`, XORing it and writing it back.

Comment: Sir that means for reading the status of PORT we must use PINx and for writing we must use PORTx...

Comment: @ShrikantVaishnav yes please take a look into the the data sheet section about digital inputs